# Python - I've been trying to Increment a semi annual raise (from PSet_1b of MIT 6.0001) but the results are the same

Tags: python, if-statement

> PSet_1a - Baseline

> This prompts the user for the cost of their dream house, their salary, the portion of their monthly salary that they are willing to save, and returns the number of months it would take for them to have a down payment (25% of the cost of their dream house)

```
total_cost = float(input('How much is the dream house? ')) 
portion_down_payment = 0.25
current_savings = 0
r = 0.04
annual_salary = float(input('What is your salary? '))
portion_saved = float(input('What is the amount saved per month? '))
monthly_salary = annual_salary / 12.0

amount_down_payment = total_cost * portion_down_payment
portion_amount = monthly_salary * portion_saved
months = 0

while current_savings <= amount_down_payment:
    current_savings += portion_amount + (current_savings * (r / 12))
    months += 1
    print(current_savings, months)
```

> PSet_1b - Adjusted for Semi-Annual Raise

> Prompts the user as the same above but this one asks for a semi annual rate, turns it into a number to add to the annual raise.

```
total_cost = float(input('How much is the dream house? '))
portion_down_payment = 0.25
current_savings = 0
r = 0.04

annual_salary = float(input('What is your salary? ')) 
portion_saved = float(input('What is the amount saved per month? '))
semi_annual_rate = float(input('What is the rate of your semi-annual_raise? '))
monthly_salary = annual_salary / 12.0
semi_annual_raise = monthly_salary * semi_annual_rate

amount_down_payment = total_cost * portion_down_payment
portion_amount = monthly_salary * portion_saved

months = 0

while current_savings <= amount_down_payment:
    months += 1
    if months % 6 == 0:
        annual_salary += semi_annual_raise
        
    current_savings += portion_amount + (current_savings * (r / 12))
    print(current_savings, months)
```

> Both programs return the same results when I run them and I have been trying to figure out why and how on my own for a few hours now without much improvement.

Comment: You're updating `annual_salary` but not `portion_amount`, which is what's actually used in your calculation.

Comment: If I'm not getting it wrong, you are not using `semi_annual_raise` or `annual_salary` in your calculations; so that's definitely same code as the first one.

Comment: @Randy, if I update the portion_amount then it will add to it every month, not every 6 months which I intend.

Comment: You need to update it in the block where you update annual salary so that it only does it when the raise occurs.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to update portion_amount per 6 months through if statement and not to go through it semi_annual_raise on the annual_salary.

Thanks to Randy from the comments.